# Does JavaFX have a way to create Grouped Stacked Bar Charts?

Tags: java, charts, javafx, bar-chart, stacked-chart

I've migrated from JFreeChart to JavaFX charts but I can't seem to find any sort of equivalent to [GroupedStackedBarRenderer](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/category/GroupedStackedBarRenderer.html). Is there a way I could obtain the effect of having stacked bar charts that are grouped together?

[image: GroupedStackedBarRenderer example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The chart referenced in your question was generated by [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/index.html).  You can use JFreeChart in JavaFX via the [FXGraphics2D](http://www.jfree.org/fxgraphics2d/) bridge.  There should be samples of how to do so included in the latest JFreeChart developer source distribution bundle.

> FXGraphics2D is an implementation of Java2D's Graphics2D API that targets a JavaFX canvas. It has been built for use with Orson Charts and JFreeChart, but will be generally useful for any code that uses the Graphics2D API.

---

JavaFX does have it's own in-built [JavaFX charting library](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/charts.htm).  However, as far I know, the implementation does not include a built-in chart that matches the [GroupedStackBarRenderer](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/category/GroupedStackedBarRenderer.html) referenced in your question.  You could extend the JavaFX charting library to create a custom chart that performs that function, however to do so would likely be a pretty complicated task and providing detailed information on that is probably outside the standard scope of a StackOverflow answer.